# How can i put the text box next to the image

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a website and i'm trying to add a textbox to the navbar.
Here's my HTML & CSS:

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #323232;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}

.search {
  /*empty*/
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <img src=https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fclipground.com%2Fimages%2Fguy-writing-clipart-transparent-no-watermark-3.png&f=1&nofb=1 height="50">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" style="left: 100;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `display: flex`, and then center the search box with `align-items: center`

If you're going to being using `display: flex`, you should also consider checking out [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), as it shows a lot of helpful examples, and is a nice little cheatsheet

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #323232;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" style="left: 100;">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This shall be enough.

```
.search{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Or you could use flexbox, even better.

```
.search {
    display:flex;
    align-items:stretch;
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #323232;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.search {
    display:flex;
    align-items:stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <img src=https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fclipground.com%2Fimages%2Fguy-writing-clipart-transparent-no-watermark-3.png&f=1&nofb=1 height="50">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" style="left: 100;">
  </div>
</div>
```